# SharePoint 2013 - MySites - SharePoint permissions grant access to file, but users get 'access denied'?

Tags: permissions, mysite, onenote

I have a funny situation involving MySites and OneNote documents.

I have gone into SharePoint mysites site and verified that I have permissions given to a particular Document Library with permissions inherited from the Site Collection.

The MySite site collection has a `Sharepoint Viewers` sharepoint group, and `Everyone` is a member of the group. Pretty typical stuff. Nothing special.

Sharepoint search allows users to search for this document. All good.

But when they click on the document, they get permission denied.

I used the CSOM api and it also shows the same thing - the OneNote document inherits permissions from the site collection, and it is granting read access to `Everyone` via the `Sharepoint Viewers` group.

Is there some special situation where you can have sharepoint permissions set up to allow access to a doc, but you cannot view that document? Particularly something special with OneNote documents on MySites perhaps? Or perhaps the `Everyone` claim is special in some way causing this confusing behavior?

UPDATE: I just went back and ran this test again, and suddenly users can access the document. Maybe this is some sort of intermittent problem that I should open a trouble ticket with Microsoft about?

UPDATE 2: I found this same situation for non-OneNote documents today. So this has nothing to do with OneNote specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep points to comment, so I have to leave this as an answer; which it is not. I have had similar issues with SharePoint, but I think my setup was a little different. I had a couple documents I wanted to give open permission/access to where the parent folder was restricted.

Despite me making the docs openly accessible, I had people, VPs included, say they couldn't access the documents. The only fix I could come up with at the time was to give individual access to anyone who requested access. I never did find a solution outside of creating a folder that was designated as publicly accessible.

It's definitely a hack and doesn't really resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response @brehma. But this doesn't sound like the same situation. I am experiencing the reverse issue of what you said.